# SharePoint populate Choice field value using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery-ajax

[image]

```
       var ArrivalCity = (data.aircraftView[0].arcftSchedList[0].tripArrivalCity);
       $('select[title="Select the Destination"]').val(ArrivalCity);

       var ArrivalCity1 = (data.aircraftView[1].arcftSchedList[0].tripArrivalCity);
       $('select[title="Select the Destination"]').val(ArrivalCity1);
```

I am trying to populate the choice field from jquery on the SharePoint list. I am able to get the values but it is not getting stored in my choice field defined. I have multiple values coming into the arrival city and departure city, so I am getting those values from rest api. I am not sure why they are not getting populated in my choice field. I have attached a screenshot of the selector. 
 Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: is there anything I need to change it this line of code? $('select[title="Select the Origin"]').val(DepartureCity);

Comment: First of all check for the selector. Are you getting the desired select element using $('select[title="Select the Origin"]').val(DepartureCity)??

Comment: Yes Select the origin is the choice field in sharepoint list new item. And the selector is select for the choice field. I am not sure what should I use to populate the values in the choice field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append options to select element.

```
$('select[title="Select the Destination"]').append($('<option></option>').val("value1").html("text1"));
            $('select[title="Select the Destination"]').append($('<option></option>').val("value2").html("text2"));
```

Update:

```
var Options = [{ "Value": "Value1", "Text": "Text1" },
        { "Value": "Value2", "Text": "Text2" },
        {"Value": "Value3","Text":"Text3"}]
        $(function () {
            $.each(Options, function () {
                $('select[title="Select the Destination"]').append($('<option></option>').val(this.Value).html(this.Text));
            })
            //$('select[title="Select the Destination"]').append($('<option></option>').val("value1").html("text1"));
            //$('select[title="Select the Destination"]').append($('<option></option>').val("value2").html("text2"));
        })
```

Comment: I am basically getting the values from the json data  and storing them in a variable and then appending to the option. How can i do that ?

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: How can I populate values based on two changes say for example I select date and one more column, based on the selection of date and one more column other fields should populate.